# listing/creation of PV failing using kubernetes RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

i have a service account which has access to one of the app namespace. I have created a cluster role and rolebinding and mapped it to the associated Service account in that namespace.
Everything works as expected except the listing/creation of PV on the cluster level. Can some please help.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: dxf-clusterrole
rules:
  -
    apiGroups:
      - ""
      - apps
      - batch
      - extensions
      - policy
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      - roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      - authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - secrets
      - configmaps
      - deployments
      - endpoints
      - horizontalpodautoscalers
      - jobs
      - limitranges
      - namespaces
      - nodes
      - pods
      - persistentvolumes
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - resourcequotas
      - replicasets
      - replicationcontrollers
      - serviceaccounts
      - services
      - role
      - rolebindings

    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
      - create
      - delete
  - nonResourceURLs: ["*"]
    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list



apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: dxf-clusterrolebinding
  namespace: dxf-uat
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: dxf-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dxf-deployer
  namespace: dxf-uat
```

User "system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer" cannot get resource "persistentvolumes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four Kubernetes objects: [Role, ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole), [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) and [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding), that we can use to configure needed **RBAC** rules. `Role` and `RoleBinding` are namespaced and `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` are cluster scoped resources.

As you can see in the [RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding):

> A RoleBinding grants permissions within a specific namespace whereas a ClusterRoleBinding grants that access cluster-wide.

---

Your problem is with all cluster-scope resources such as `PersistentVolumes`, `Nodes`, `Namespaces` etc:

```
$ kubectl get nodes --as=system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer
Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

$ kubectl get persistentvolumes -n dxf-uat --as=system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer
Error from server (Forbidden): persistentvolumes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer" cannot list resource "persistentvolumes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

$ kubectl get namespaces --as=system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

You need to create a `ClusterRole` with all cluster scoped resources you want to have access from the `dxf-deployer` `ServiceAccount` and then bind this `ClusterRole` to the `dxf-deployer` `ServiceAccount` using `ClusterRoleBinding`.

In the example below, I've granted permissions for `dxf-deployer` `ServiceAccount` to `Nodes` and  `PersistentVolumes`:

```
$ cat cluster-scope-permissions.yml
# cluster-scope-permissions.yml
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-scope-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - persistentvolumes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - delete
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-scope-rolebinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-scope-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dxf-deployer
  namespace: dxf-uat
```

Finally, we can check if it works as expected:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cluster-scope-permissions.yml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-scope-role created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-scope-rolebinding created


$ kubectl get nodes --as=system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
node1                                      Ready    <none>   5h11m   v1.18.12-gke.1210
node2                                      Ready    <none>   5h11m   v1.18.12-gke.1210

$ kubectl get persistentvolumes -n dxf-uat --as=system:serviceaccount:dxf-uat:dxf-deployer
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-0ba2fd12-c883-45b8-b52d-a6c826a2775a   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/my-jenkins   standard                131m
pvc-b4b7a4c8-c9ad-4e83-b1ee-663b3e4d938b   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/debug-pvc    standard                5h12m
```